# space around top of the background image

Tags: swiftui, ios14

Trying to set an image as a background for my view in SwiftUI. Using Xcode 12 beta and iOS 14.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Image("background")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, alignment: .center)
            .clipped()
    }
}
```

}

Output

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should be enough (tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4)

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Image("background")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I was wondering why do I need to add that?

Comment: @karmjitsingh, to make it full screen out of safe area.

Comment: If I remove the modifier, why is it showing the space only on the top and why not at the bottom.

Comment: @karmjitsingh, you hardcoded frame to size of screen, but center of safe area is not at the center of physical screen to which you sized, so you see of what you got.